# div and button link to the CSS and Javascript Same time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, class

```js
start_btn.onclick = () => {
  info_box.classList.add("activeInfo");
};
```

```css
.btn-12 {
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 200px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  line-height: 42px;
  -webkit-perspective: 230px;
  perspective: 230px;
}

.btn-12 span {
  background: rgb(0, 172, 238);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 172, 238, 1) 0%, rgba(2, 126, 251, 1) 100%);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.btn-12 span:nth-child(1) {
  box-shadow: -7px -7px 20px 0px #fff9, -4px -4px 5px 0px #fff9, 7px 7px 20px 0px #0002, 4px 4px 5px 0px #0001;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
}

.btn-12 span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
}

.btn-12:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.btn-12:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="start_btn">
  <button class="btn-12"><span>ｲ   ҽ.</span><span>Click Me</span></button>
</div>
```

Above Code: not show button in the out put result

I rename the class from "btn-12" and "start_btn" to "start_btn1" and "btn-12" or "start_btn" and "btn-12l"

**it's Working**

Comment: "it"s Working" -> this is a bit confusing? are you asking why your solution works? Can you please be clearer about what you get and what you expect from your code?

Comment: When I remove the link from CSS or javascript It will work, but I can't use JavaScript and CSS at the same time (Only one link works)

Comment: In .btn-12 **position: relative;** is breaking it

Comment: For the CSS part @imvain2's comment is right, concerning the javascript, if it breaks it, it's probably because you have an error somewhere, or a bad interaction with the styles. We don't seem to have all the relevant parts to tell you, as `info_box` doesn't exist in the HTML part

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, you have some conflicting Styling. When `position: relative;` is removed, it works as expected.

Consider the following.

```js
start_btn.onclick = () => {
  console.log("Click Event");
  info_box.classList.add("activeInfo");
};
```

```css
.btn-12 {
  align-items: center;
  /*
  position: relative;
  */
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 200px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  line-height: 42px;
  -webkit-perspective: 230px;
  perspective: 230px;
}

.btn-12 span {
  background: rgb(0, 172, 238);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 172, 238, 1) 0%, rgba(2, 126, 251, 1) 100%);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.btn-12 span:nth-child(1) {
  box-shadow: -7px -7px 20px 0px #fff9, -4px -4px 5px 0px #fff9, 7px 7px 20px 0px #0002, 4px 4px 5px 0px #0001;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
}

.btn-12 span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -20px;
}

.btn-12:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.btn-12:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="start_btn">
  <button class="btn-12"><span>ｲ   ҽ.</span><span>Click Me</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You For Your Response But  I am  very Sorry Dude i Fixed it i consider your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Above code

change to HTML:-

```
 <div class ="start_btn">
  <button class="btn-12"><span>ｲ   ҽ.</span><span>Click Me</span></button>
</div>
```

and CSS Like this:-

```
   #start_btn.btn-12{
```

align-items: center;
....
}

add "#start_btn in the CSS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).